# Crystal reports - Failed to retrieve data from the database.Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONVERT'

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I am setting up my development environment and am facing issues accessing Crystal Reports using SQL Server, especially with DATETIME parameters.

Other reports work.  From Visual Studio I am getting `Failed to retrieve data from the database with vendor code 156.`

After surfing through nothing improved and I traced the execution through SQL Profiler and noticed

`CONVERT(DATETIME, '2017-02-09 00:00:00', 120)` is passed as parameter where the functions are not allowed as values for a SQL parameter.

After searching for this specific issue most of the answers were related to ODBC drivers.  Any help trouble shooting further would be appreciated.

This is for SQL Server 2012 with SP4 and Crystal Reports 11 R2.

Comment: do you have to pass a datetime type?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu Yes am passing date time

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when Crystal Reports 2013 connects with SQL Server 2012 via Visual Studio

Setting the logon property of the object Report Document, with Provider pointing to SQL Native Client 11.0 resolved the issue.

Provider = "SQLNCLI11"

The below link describes the exact issue more precisely

https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/1478053